# Redux store not being passed to props on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Learning Redux and React, and I'm having an issue where I have the store created, and passed over to my `<Provider>` through react-redux, but I get an empty object when logging in the console.

```
import {  createStore,  applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import  logger from 'redux-logger';
import  thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import uuid from 'uuid';


var defaultState = {
  tasks: [{
    key: uuid.v4(),
    name: 'learn Redux',
    description: 'Learn how to create a completely statefully managed application.',
    priority: 1,
    notes: [{
      key: uuid.v4(),
      content: 'Creation of the store is paramount. One must import {createStore, applyMiddleware from redux package}, then define the root reducer, and create the store with applymiddleware, and then export the store.'
    }],
  }, ]
};

var root = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  return state;
};

var store = createStore(root, applyMiddleware(thunk,logger));

export default store;
```

I think the issue may lie with how I'm passing it to the `<Provider>` component, but that also could be wrong. Just for good measure, here is my App component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import store from './store/createStore';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    // let tasks = this.props.tasks.map(x => {
    //   return <p>{x.name}</p>
    // })
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <h1>Nothing to see here.</h1>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where are you rendering your app ? You can pass props to your app directly when  rendering <App myProp={'foo'} />. Did you connect it with react-redux.connect ? If yes, pass it the props you want in mapStateToProps

Comment: that was the case, I forgot the connect method and mapstatetoprops...

Comment: Note that it seems you were trying to get your whole state as app properties. In a redux architecture, it's good to design your app so that each component receives only the props it needs, not the whole state

Comment: Yep. Just did "most" of a redux tutorial, so these are some really good notes! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redux state does not automatically show up as props everywhere; and rightfully so. If that is the case, the performance would be devastating unless you have custom `shouldComponentUpdate`.

What you need to use is [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) the redux state to your component. For your example, it'll be something like:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

...

// Replace last line with this:
export default connect(
  state => ({ tasks: state.tasks }),
  null,
)(App);
```

Now, `this.props.tasks` will be the `tasks` in your redux state.

Answer (score 2):

`<Provider>` "provides" the store prop to components placed below it that use `connect()`.

You can't place the `<Provider>` within a component's render function and change the props passed to it. It's already too late at that point. The props are what they are.

That will happen above this component in the tree, either another component or during your `ReactDOM.render` call.

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry to stalk you with this and I'm not sure if I made the [problem](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6196) clear. I have searched a lot and did not find a great solution for something that should be a common thing (React+Redux+react-router). The question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50719919/1641941) but thought contributors of the project would have ran into this one and properly solved it. Just that the documentation isn't showing up anywhere I've been looking.