# How and where to dispatch action when react router changes props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I may be missing something here, change in react-router params using Link will cause the props to change with the new param(s) and trigger an update cycle.

You can't dispatch an action in the update cycle but that's the only place where the parameter is available. I need to get new data when the day parameter changes in my stateless component.

The component has 2 links, previous and next day. The previous day looks like this:

```
<Link to={"/sessions/" + prefDay}>{prefDay}</Link>
```

[UPDATE]

Here is the solution so far:

The Overview component is just a function taking props and returning jsx, the following is the container that will check if date is set and if it's not it'll redirect. If date is set then it'll return Overview.

It also checks if the router day paramater changed, if it did then it'll set dispatchFetch to true.

This will then cause the render function to asynchronously dispatch the getData action.

Not sure if there would be another way to do this, I would prefer to listen to events from router and dispatch the events from there but there is no (working) way to listen to the router.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Overview from '../components/Overview';
import { getData } from '../actions';
import { selectOverview } from "../selectors";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";


const defaultDate = "2018-01-02";
const mapStateToProps = (lastProps => (state, ownProps) => {
  var dispatchFetch = false;
  if (lastProps.match.params.day !== ownProps.match.params.day) {
    lastProps.match.params.day = ownProps.match.params.day;
    dispatchFetch = true;
  }
  return {
    ...selectOverview(state),
    routeDay: ownProps.match.params.day,
    dispatchFetch
  }
})({ match: { params: {} } });
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getData
};
class RedirectWithDefault extends Component {
  render() {
    //I would try to listen to route change and then dispatch getData when
    //  routeDay changes but none of the methods worked
    //  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3554
    //    onChange in FlexkidsApp.js never gets called and would probably 
    //      result in the same problem of dispatching an event in update cycle
    //    browserHistory does not exist in react-router-dom
    //    this.props.history.listen didn't do anything when trying it in the constructor
    //So how does one dispatch an event when props change in stateless components?
    //  can try to dispatch previous and next day instead of using Link component
    //  but that would not update the url in the location bar
    if (this.props.dispatchFetch) {
      Promise.resolve().then(() => this.props.getData(this.props.routeDay));
    }
    return (this.props.routeDay)//check if url has a date (mapStateToProps would set this)
      ? Overview(this.props)
      : <Redirect//no date, redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/list/" + defaultDate
        }}
      />
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RedirectWithDefault);
```

Answer (score 1):

Intially I expect your Router is like,

```
<Route path="/sessions/:prefDay" component={MyComponent}/>
```

You will have to do this in getDerivedStateFromProps(),

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.prefDay !== nextProps.match.params.prefDay) {

     return {
     prefDay: nextProps.match.params.prefDay,
     };
   }
   // Return null to indicate no change to state.
   return null;
  }
```

Comment: Is the requirement is like, you wanna open a new url and send the dispatch from that component?

Comment: `<Link to={"/sessions/" + prefDay}>{prefDay}</Link>` tells react-router to update the props and sets the url, that works fine. But updating props does not cause `componentDidMount` to be called so I don't know where to dispatch the action when react-router updates props.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, so you are clicking the link to prev day and then rendering the same component and there by showing new data in the same component. Ok, editing the answer according to that

Comment: I am not using state but using mapStateToProps with connect in stateless component, now there is an error `Warning: SessionsOverview: Did not properly initialize state during construction. Expected state to be an object, but it was undefined.` Since this is a static function there is no way of knowing if props changed unless you use state as well?

Comment: Ok, you will have to intialise state in constructor for clearing this error.You can do it like, `constructor(props){super(props);this.state={prefDay:this.props.match.params.prefDay}}`

Comment: So I have to use state, then the component would not be stateless anymore. I am suspecting this should be handled elsewhere though for stateless components. Maybe in the middleware checking if route changed and then just dispatch actions there.

Comment: Lifecycle methods are not available for stateless components.

Comment: And I just found out that react-router does not dispatch any actions so redux middleware is a bust as well.

Comment: I have updated my question, cant actually use `getDerivedStateFromProps` because `this.props.getData` is unavailable there. So calling it (dispatching an action) is again in the update cycle. Now the container of the component will check for changes (somehow react-router has no working events) and asynchronously dispatch an action in the render function. This is not a good way and may as well use instance methods from the update cycle but I don't see any other way since react-router just changes props so the update cycle is the only place where the date is available for dispatching the action.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried componentWillReceiveProps?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props){
   if(this.props.data != props.data && this.props.state.routeDay){
     this.props.getData(props.state.routeDay);
   }
}
```

Comment: [No I did not](https://hackernoon.com/evil-things-you-do-with-redux-dispatch-in-updating-lifecycle-methods-ad116de882d4) follow the link and you'll get to an explanation about not dispatching actions in react life cycle methods.

Comment: Ah ok, I just changed the code above a bit. You always want to reference the (props) variable inside this function instead of this.props to get the latest props.

Comment: you can't dispatch actions in react life cycle methods because you'll get warnings that you should not do such a thing. I'm looking for a way to detect changes in the react-router and see if I can dispatch actions from there but with no luck.

Comment: componentDidMount is a react life cycle method

Comment: I think he meant the updating cycle

Comment: I think this is fine, especially if you do enough checks before you fire the action, to make sure the action needs to be fired.

Comment: One of us has a misunderstanding of Redux, as I understand it you can't dispatch actions while updating.

Comment: Just dooo it :)

Comment: or try componentDidUpdate(), then you are not updating anymore I guess

Comment: It's still in the same callstack

Answer (score 0):

To add parameter to route you need in router do this

```
<Route 
     path="/sessions/:prefDay" 
                ....
/>
```

It means that now "/sessions/" rout have a parameter named "prefDay"
Example /sessions/:prefDay

and now in Link component need to add this parameter

```
<Link to={"/sessions/" + prefDay}>{prefDay}</Link>
```

You can get this value from url like this

```
this.props.match.params.prefDay
```

Comment: The link works, it updates the url and react-router sets the props again but `componentDidMount` is never called again so no new data is ever fetched. I can use Rohith's answer and never have my location updated or use your answer and never have my data fetched when react-router sets the props.

Answer (score 0):

In RedirectWithDefaults which is a container of the stateless component I added componentDidMount (not an update cycle method):

```
const historyListener = (lastDay => (props,currentDay) => {
    if(lastDay !== currentDay){
        lastDay = currentDay;
        if(!isNaN(new Date(currentDay))){
            console.log("getting:",currentDay);
            props.getData(currentDay);
        }
    }
})(undefined);

class RedirectWithDefault extends Component {
    componentDidMount(history) {
        this.props.getData(this.props.routeDay || defaultDate);
        this.unListen = this.props.history.listen((location) => {
            historyListener(
                this.props,
                location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]
            );
        });
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.unListen();
    }
```

Removed code from the render function. Now when it mounts it'll dispatch the action to load data and when the route changes it will dispatch it again but not in the update cycle.